# Sending DatagramPacket in android but nothing happens

Tags: android, sockets, networking, packet, datagram

I am trying to build a packet, with DatagramPacket, and then send it using DatagramSocket and retrieve an answer from the remote server.

after running this code on my `MainActivity` through my device, I just get a blank page, looks like it is "stuck" while trying to receive an answer from the server but nothing happens:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream message = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream headerStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        message = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(intToByteArray(0)); // flags
        outputStream.write("08".getBytes());   // client type
        outputStream.write(intToByteArray(0)); // min version
        outputStream.write(intToByteArray(2)); // max version
        byte[] payload = outputStream.toByteArray();

        byte[] packettypeIdByte = "DD00".getBytes(); // packet type
        headerStream.write(packettypeIdByte);
        headerStream.write(intToByteArray(payload.length));
        headerStream.write(intToByteArray(0)); // version
        byte[] header = headerStream.toByteArray();

        message.write(header);
        message.write(payload);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // for discover
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("XX.XX.XX.XX");
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.toByteArray(), message.toByteArray().length);

        int port = XXXX
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
        ds.receive(packet);
        String str = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
        Log.d("pac", str);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong? or what is the proper way for using datagramPacket and datagramSocket?

Comment: Shouldn't you send the packet first? Or explain what ds.receive(packet); does.

Comment: Are you using a thread for this internet code?

Comment: @blackapps I'm not sending the packet by this way? yes, I want to send the packet `message` through the socket `ds` and then wait for a response. I'm not using another thread to send it, I added `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);` ro allow sending from main thread

Comment: You did not explain what ds.receive(packet) does.

Comment: Remove that strictmode. Bad practice. Use a thread. Well for a test its ok..

Comment: @blackapps yes I'm doing it now just for a test.
`ds.receive(packet)` as far as I can tell, sends the packet and waits for receiving back data.

Comment: Isnt there a return value?

Comment: @blackapps no there isn't